# Xcode 4.6.3 - Can't select tab bar item on Storyboard?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, xcode4.6.3

I'm currently on Xcode 4.6.3. I used storyboards in my project. Inside the storyboard is a tab bar controller and two table view controllers. I have the tab bar controller as the root view and I have it linked up with the two table view controllers via "relationship segue - view controllers".

The main problem I'm experiencing is that I can't seem to select the tab bar item in the storyboard so that I can change the name and the image for that tab bar. When I click on the tab bar, its properties does not appear in my inspector view, or at least, I don't see any property for the title and image. All I see is this

[image]

I've read through tutorials online that you can change the title and image of a tab bar item easily just by clicking the tab bar item to reveal the properties. Is this an issue with  my version of Xcode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I already figured it out. It has nothing to do with the Xcode version. The tab bar item subview was in the two table view controllers so just select it there to edit title and image. There's no tab bar item subview in the tab bar controller itself.

Answer (score 3):

I see you have connected your tabs to TableViewControllers...You can edit by clicking the bottom tab of one of the TableViewControllers that you have connected to. If this doesn't work first try a sample project by just keeping your tabs as simple ViewControllers.